# android http post request vs SocketTimeOutException

Tags: http, android, java

Пишу приложение под android. Приложение коннектится к Facebook
и начинает гонять json-запросы через `http post`. Все идет хорошо минут 10. Потом я начинаю ловить ошибку `SocketTimeOutException` и запросы с телефона не уходят. Еще минут через 10 будто бы перестаёт зависать и запросы снова начинают посылаться до следующего зависания.

```
public static String httpTPRequest(String url,String params) {
  Debug.log(TAG,"req:"+params);   // REQUEST
  String response = Static.EMPTY;
  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
  httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
  //httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
  HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
  try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    if(entity != null)
      response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.log(TAG,"tp server request:"+e.getMessage());
  }
  Debug.log(TAG,"resp:" + response);   // RESPONSE
  response;
```

Comment: может фейс бук блокирует айпишнег из-за частых тычков?

Comment: увы нет, т.к. код использую при коннекте к разным api серверам и везде одно и тоже. Дело в том, что запрос даже перестает уходить с девайса, что показал глубокий дебаг. Значит проблема в коде.

Comment: Конкретно с этими классами я не работал, но может в них тоже нужно выполнять закрытие/очистку сокетов, например типа httpResponse.close(); или httpResponse.clear();

Comment: Хм. Спасибо, как вариант попробую !

Answer (score 1):

вынесено из комментариев.

---

возможно, требуется выполнять закрытие/очистку сокетов, например типа `httpResponse.close();` или `httpResponse.clear();`